# Appium - Could not find 'apksigner.jar'

Tags: mobile-automation

Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.17.4.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\cmdline-tools\bin\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LBV2D64', ip: '192.168.6.108', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.17.4.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\cmdline-tools\bin\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LBV2D64', ip: '192.168.6.108', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:338)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:96)
    at appiumTest.CalculatorOpenTest.main(CalculatorOpenTest.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:193)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.17.4.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\cmdline-tools\bin\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LBV2D64', ip: '192.168.6.108', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.17.4.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\\cmdline-tools\\bin\\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\cmdline-tools\bin\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 19 more
```

My code:

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

//import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class CalculatorOpenTest {

    static AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable 
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"UiAutomator2");
        //cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        //cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator1");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Roy Galaxy M51");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "RZ8N91NX7WF");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11");
        
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.calculator");
        
        URL url= new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url,cap);
        System.out.println("Application Started Successfully....");
    

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please at least format your code properly when you want to drown us in logs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have downloaded command-line tools and haven't extracted "build-tools" folder yet then open `cmd` and go to folder's location where your SDKManager is present and then run the following command:

```
//sdkmanager build-tools version number like following command

sdkmanager build-tools;31.0.0
```

`apksigner.jar` comes inside the build-tools\version number\lib folder.

After running the above command, set the path (where your apksigner.jar is present) in environment variable.

You can check list of build tools versions from following link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Or simply you can run following command in the `cmd`:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\Users\admin\Downloads\commandlinetools-win-6858069_latest\cmdline-tools\bin\path-to-where-cmdline-tools-is\platform-tools\apksigner.jar"
```

it clearly says in the error , what is missing . Try to install latest build tool

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010756/6793637

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- Check .JAR in path `/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/apksigner`
- I am using 33.0.0 this version could be different for you but focus on location
- You can find .JAR if not then I would say please re-install android-sdk again
- Because fixing each and every file from big android-sdk could be tedious task. Re-installation could fix issue easily