# Appium-Could not find ''apksigner.jar''

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\Desktop\sdk-tools'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'RANA', ip: '192.168.10.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\Desktop\sdk-tools'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'RANA', ip: '192.168.10.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\Desktop\sdk-tools'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'RANA', ip: '192.168.10.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.21.1.apk'. Original error: Could not find 'apksigner.jar' in ["C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\platform-tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\emulator\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\cmdline-tools\\latest\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\tools\\bin\\apksigner.jar","C:\\Users\\Rana Hamza\\Desktop\\sdk-tools\\apksigner.jar"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Rana Hamza\Desktop\sdk-tools'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Rana Hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004884/cant-find-apksigner-executable-to-manually-sign-apk/55588753

Comment: i did not download android studio i downloaded just sdk manager tool and did nit find there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appium - Could not find 'apksigner.jar'](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/47146/appium-could-not-find-apksigner-jar)

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- Check .JAR in path `/Android/sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/apksigner`
- I am using 33.0.0 this version could be different for you but focus on location
- You can find .JAR if not then I would say please re-install android-sdk again
- Because fixing each and every file from big android-sdk could be tedious task. Re-installation could fix issue easily